# Draw a smooth curve through a set of n points

Tags: java, rendering, graphics2d, curve, smoothing

I'm working on a game displaying a route from a specific start point to the cursor. Since the current system is very old (probably about 10 years or so...) and partly broken, I want to rewrite this code from scratch.
Let's say I have an array of points on my screen -*the last point being my cursor*-, and a Graphics2D object. How would I draw a line going smooth through all of those points using the shortest way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I draw a line going smooth through all of those points using the shortest way possible

This requirement is a bit contradictory. The shortest curve through a list of points is a polygon but a polygon is in general not smooth.

However, what you are looking for is probably spline interpolation. This is not available in the standard Java packages but you could use `SplineInterpolator` in Apache Commons Math.

Comment: Yes, spline interpolation is what I'm looking for... No, the splineinterpolator needs a increasing x value for it to work. Since this line is a route on a map x could increase and decrease at it's will

Comment: @RoiEX: You can use the point index as increasing X value (curve parameter) and then use two separate `SplineInterpolator`s for the actual X and Y coordinates.

Comment: But how would I get 1 curve out of these two?

Comment: @RoiEX: Don't plot the curve parameter, just the resulting X and Y coordinates.

Comment: Ok I got it... Only one question how do I draw those coordinates on my graphics2D object? By drawing points?

Comment: I think it's better to draw lines instead of points. the challenging part is to find a suitable step size for the curve parameter.

Comment: That could indeed be a problem since we are using index values